# Ubuntu - Forward packets that have destination subdomain.example.com to internal LAN hosts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, security, iptables

I have an Ubuntu server as a gateway in my network that serves multiple services.
I want to have those services split up into multiple Ubuntu servers (physical and/or Virtual) for more computing power and better organisation.
I have only one public IP available.
DNS is configured and answers for "example.com"

Please see the diagram below for more information:

```
                                      /\                        -----------------
                                     /  \                       |               |
                                    /    \  <-----------------> |  Remote Host  |
                                   /      \                     |               |
                                  /Internet\                    -----------------
                                  \        /
                                   \      /
                                    \    /
                                     \  /
                                      \/
                                      |
                                      |
                              -------eth0------
                              |     1.2.3.4   |
                              | Ubuntu Server |
                              |    Gateway    |
                              |  192.168.0.1  |
                              -------eth1------
                                      |
                                      |
                                      |
                              -----------------
                              |               |
                              |   LAN Switch  |
                              |               |
                              -----------------
                                      /\
                                     /  \
                                    /    \
                                   /      \
                                  /        \
                                 /          \
                                /            \
                               /              \
                              /                \
                             /                  \
                   -------eth0------     ------eth0-------
                   | Ubuntu server |     | Ubuntu server |
                   |      SRV1     |     |      SRV2     |
                   | 192.168.0.10  |     |  192.168.0.20 |
                   |               |     |               |
                   -----------------     -----------------
```

Now, what I need is to forward all packets that come from a remote host to srv1.example.com to internal server SRV1 and all packets that come to srv2.example.com to SRV2. I also need those servers accessible from LAN.

I know that this is can be done for WWW traffic using reverse proxy.

But what if I want to use SSH? (Example: I need to connect to SRV1 via SSH by using SSH user@srv1.example.com.

I am looking to do this without port forwarding (SSH port for gateway 22, SSH port forward for SRV1 2201, SSH port forward for SRV 2202)

Can this be done using IPTables or any other tool?

Can this be done using VMs easier (I am also thinking of implementing KVM Hypervisor)?

Sorry if my English.

Thank you very much,
Alex

Comment: About SSH. You can buy a second real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot do this.

All TCP client requests start with the client making a DNS query,  where the client gets the IP adddress of the remote host. Then it opens the TCP connection to the IP address and specified port.

Therefore there is no way for the remote server to know which domain the client is connecting to. The client has to provide this information in the protocol used inside TCP.

For example in HTTP there is the `Host:` header sent with the request, which indicates what domain the client is connecting to. With HTTPS, there is the TLS SNI field for the same purpose.

In SSH, there is no such mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nginx to do that.

For the WWW traffic you need to configure a reverse Proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name srv1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name srv2.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.20/;
    }
}
```

Detailed documentation you can find here: [Nginx Documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

For your SSH you need to use the Stream option of Nginx:

```
stream {
    upstream srv1 {
        server srv1.example.com:22
        server 192.168.0.10:22
        server unix:/tmp/srv1;
    }
    upstream srv2 {
        server srv2.example.com:22
        server 192.168.0.20:22
        server unix:/tmp/srv2;
    }
    server {
        listen     2201;
        server_name srv1.example.com;
        proxy_pass srv1;
    }
    server {
        listen     2202;
        server_name srv2.example.com;
        proxy_pass srv2;
    }
}
```

Here you can find the documentation for the [Stream Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)

So you can reach your website on port 80 and ssh of srv1 on port 2201 and ssh of srv2 on port 2202. 
So in the end it is still port forwarding but you can handle it with nginx instead of iptables.

Best Regards
ThoBe